# Visual Studio C++ not recognizing literal string argument as const string reference

Tags: c++, .net, string, arrays, type-mismatch

I have a C++ class with a constructor defined as follows.

```
SomeClass( const string & input );
```

I have some client code that I believe should use this constructor implicitly, as follows.

```
SomeClass sc;
sc = "sstr";
```

However I am getting the following compiler error.

```
//Error: no operator "=" matches these operands, 
//operand types are: Fraction = const char[4]
```

If I alter the SomeClass constructor to the following, the compiler error disappears.

```
SomeClass( const char * input );
```

I am using Visual Studio 11, and .NET 4.5.

Clearly the literal char array is not being seen as a string by the compiler.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there something I am missing?

Ideally, and what I expect, is that the compiler knows that a string can also be a character array, but I am not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only one user defined  conversion is attempted when you call `operator=`.  To convert the string literal to the default assignment argument of your class it takes 2 steps, first to `std::string`, then to an instance of your class.  `=` on a non declaration is assignment, not construction.  Try overriding `operator=`...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do

```
 SomeClass sc;  // calls sc default constructor
 sc = "sstr";   // calls SomeClass::operator=
```

Instead try this

```
 SomeClass sc("sstr"); // calls SomeClass::SomeClass(const string & input)
```

Comment: Or alternately, if you still want separate steps, you can do `sc = SomeClass("sstr");`